# Linux sort by month and year

Tags: linux

I am trying to sort this data by the date such as the Oct 30 2020 column however I am not sure how

here is my current command

```
sudo find / -maxdepth 4 -size +1M  -exec ls -lh {} \; | sort -k 6hr
```

Here is my output

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 80M Oct 30  2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-11.so.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 38M Aug 27 13:02 /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 38M Sep  6 15:57 /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27M Mar 17  2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.66.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 27M Feb  2  2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 23M Feb  2  2021 /usr/bin/snap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16M Feb  2  2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snap-bootstrap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12M Feb  2  2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snap-repair
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 9.5M Feb 19  2021 /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9.0M Dec 18  2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8.8M Feb  2  2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snap-preseed
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.7M May 29 00:49 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtsan.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8.7M Feb  2  2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snap-recovery-chooser
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8.3M Feb  2  2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snapctl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7.2M Dec 18  2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6.3M Dec 16  2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5.8M Feb  2  2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snap-update-ns
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.6M Jan 16  2020 /usr/lib/file/magic.mgc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.5M Dec 16  2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5.3M Jul 28  2020 /usr/bin/python3.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.2M Jul 28  2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0
-r-xr-xr-x 2 admin1 admin1 4.7M Aug 26 02:01 /mnt/c/Windows/explorer.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.6M Feb  2  2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snap-failure
-rwxrwxrwx 1 admin1 admin1 4.3M Jun 28 16:08 /mnt/c/Python39/python39.dll
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.9M Feb  2  2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snap-exec
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.4M Oct 19  2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so.5.30.0
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 3.4M Oct 19  2020 /usr/bin/perl
```

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or a version that uses a different magic spell for `ls`:

```
sudo find / -maxdepth 4 -size +1M  -exec ls -lh --time-style=long-iso {} \; | sort -k6
```

Because it thoroughly annoys me that `ls` doesn't show years by default when timestamps lie within the last 6 months and `MMM DD YYYY` makes no sense to me in the first place I've exported `TIME_STYLE=long-iso` in my `~/.bashrc` ... so much more logical and easy to sort.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with what is called a *decorate + sort + undecorate* approach where you decorate each line by adding a new column at the end (a new column `10`) in the form `yyyymmdd` and then sort by the new last column and then remove (undecorate) the output by removing the last column.

`awk` is the normal choice, and this works quite well as long as the filenames do NOT contain whitespace (which would skew the column (field) count for `awk`).

In your case you could do:

```
sudo find / -maxdepth 4 -size +1M  -exec ls -lh {} \; |
awk 'BEGIN { 
    m["Jan"]=1; m["Feb"]=2; m["Mar"]=3; m["Apr"]=4; m["May"]=5; m["Jun"]=6; 
    m["Jul"]=7; m["Aug"]=8; m["Sep"]=9; m["Oct"]=10; m["Nov"]=11; m["Dec"]=12} 
    {
        year = ($8 ~ /:/) ? 2021 : $8
        mon = (length(m[$6]) < 2) ? "0"m[$6] : m[$6]
        day = (length($7) < 2) ? "0"$7 : $7
        $(NF+1) = year mon day
    }1
' | sort -k 10 | awk '{$NF = ""}1'
```

Above, the first call to `awk` decorates each line with the new `yyyymmdd` column (new column (field) `10`) and then the results are sorted by field 10 with sort. The second `awk` command undecorates each line.

**Example Use/Output**

Taking your shown output and placing it in the file `file` you could sort as:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
    m["Jan"]=1; m["Feb"]=2; m["Mar"]=3; m["Apr"]=4; m["May"]=5; m["Jun"]=6; 
    m["Jul"]=7; m["Aug"]=8; m["Sep"]=9; m["Oct"]=10; m["Nov"]=11; m["Dec"]=12} 
    {
        year = ($8 ~ /:/) ? 2021 : $8
        mon = (length(m[$6]) < 2) ? "0"m[$6] : m[$6]
        day = (length($7) < 2) ? "0"$7 : $7
        $(NF+1) = year mon day
    }1
' file | sort -k 10 | awk '{$NF = ""}1'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.6M Jan 16 2020 /usr/lib/file/magic.mgc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27M Mar 17 2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.66.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.2M Jul 28 2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5.3M Jul 28 2020 /usr/bin/python3.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.4M Oct 19 2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so.5.30.0
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 3.4M Oct 19 2020 /usr/bin/perl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 80M Oct 30 2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-11.so.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.5M Dec 16 2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6.3M Dec 16 2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7.2M Dec 18 2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9.0M Dec 18 2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12M Feb 2 2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snap-repair
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16M Feb 2 2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snap-bootstrap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 23M Feb 2 2021 /usr/bin/snap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 27M Feb 2 2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.9M Feb 2 2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snap-exec
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.6M Feb 2 2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snap-failure
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5.8M Feb 2 2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snap-update-ns
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8.3M Feb 2 2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snapctl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8.7M Feb 2 2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snap-recovery-chooser
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8.8M Feb 2 2021 /usr/lib/snapd/snap-preseed
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 9.5M Feb 19 2021 /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.7M May 29 00:49 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtsan.so.0.0.0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 admin1 admin1 4.3M Jun 28 16:08 /mnt/c/Python39/python39.dll
-r-xr-xr-x 2 admin1 admin1 4.7M Aug 26 02:01 /mnt/c/Windows/explorer.exe
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 38M Aug 27 13:02 /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 38M Sep 6 15:57 /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin
```

Note, you use of `-exec` in the `find` command is horribly inefficient and you are better served using the `-printf` option with available format specifiers that can create the file output in any order you like and decorate the output for you with `yyyymmdd`. That would save calling `ls -lh` on each file to produce the file listing.

There are other ways to approach this, so do not think this is the only one-way to do this. Further note the limitation on whitespace in the filename corrupting the fields if this approach is used.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `date` can parse the format printed by `ls`. The following converts the date into Unix epoch seconds and uses a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to sort the lines. The transform needs four steps:

1. Calculate the sort key
2. Prefix the data with the sort key
3. Sort the prefixed data
4. Remove the prefix

```
while read line; do
  date=$(sed 's/  / /g' <<< "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f 6-8)
  epoch=$(date -d "$date" +%s)
  printf '%s %s\n' "$epoch" "$line"
done | sort -n | sed 's/^[0-9]* //'
```

But: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Instead it would be better to tell `find` to print just the time and the file name. This can be sorted, the sort key can be removed, and finally the file names can be passed to `ls`. But you have to use the option `-f` to keep the sort order.

```
sudo find / -maxdepth 4 -size +1M -printf "%C@ %p\n" | 
sort -n | 
sed 's/^[0-9.]* //' | 
xargs ls -flh
```